# Extract nominal and standard deviation from ufloat inside a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, uncertainty

For convenience purpose I am using pandas dataframes in order to perform an uncertainty propagation on a large set on data.

I then wish to plot the nominal value of my data set but something like `myDF['colLabel'].n` won't work. How to extract the nominal and standard deviation from a dataframe in order to plot the nominal value and the errorbar?

Here is a MWE to be more consistent:

```
#%% MWE
import pandas as pd
from uncertainties import ufloat
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# building of a dataframe filled with ufloats
d = {'value1': [ufloat(1,.1),ufloat(3,.2),ufloat(5,.6),ufloat(8,.2)], 'value2': [ufloat(10,5),ufloat(50,2),ufloat(30,3),ufloat(5,1)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

# plot of value2 vs. value1 with errobars.
plt.plot(x = df['value1'].n, y = df['value2'].n)
plt.errorbar(x = df['value1'].n, y = df['value2'].n, xerr = df['value1'].s, yerr = df['value2'].s)
# obviously .n and .s won't work.
```

I get as an error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'n'` which suggest to extract the values from each series, is there a shorter way to do it than going through a loop which would separate the nominal and std values into two separated vectors?

Thanks.

EDIT: Using those functions from [the package](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html) won't work either: `uncertainties.nominal_value(df['value2'])` and `uncertainties.std_dev(df['value2'])`

Comment: You might be better off separating the value and uncertainty into separate columns. That will give you much better mileage in both hands and matplotlib. I suspect most of the advantages of vectorization will be gone if you use a custom type like that.

Comment: Infact this type is quite useful to perform uncertainty propagations :)

Comment: For what you show here, pandas mean and std functions will work fine. You'll gain more mileage implementing basic propagation yourself for a large data set than using this library and having unvectorized operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually solved it with the
`unumpy.nominal_values(arr)` and `unumpy.std_devs(arr)` functions from uncertainties.