# How to access the nominal values and uncertainties in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, uncertainty

I am using the [uncertainties](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/index.html) module along with Pandas. At present, I am able to output the dataframe with the uncertainties together to a spreadsheet. My main objective is to write the dataframe with the uncertainties in an adjacent column. But how to access the nominal values or uncertainties within dataframes. A MWE is given below.

**Present output**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 63.2+/-0.9 | 75.4+/-0.9 |
| 41.94+/-0.05 | 53.12+/-0.21 |
| 4.1+/-0.4 | 89.51+/-0.32 |
| 28.2+/-0.5 | 10.6+/-0.6 |
| 25.8+/-0.9 | 39.03+/-0.08 |
| 27.26+/-0.09 | 44.61+/-0.35 |
| 25.04+/-0.13 | 37.7+/-0.6 |
| 2.4+/-0.5 | 50.0+/-0.8 |
| 0.92+/-0.21 | 3.1+/-0.5 |
| 57.69+/-0.34 | 21.8+/-0.8 |

**Desired output**

| A | +/- | B | +/- |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 63.2 | 0.9 | 75.4 | 0.9 |
| 41.94 | 0.05 | 53.12 | 0.21 |
| 4.1 | 0.4 | 89.51 | 0.32 |
| 28.2 | 0.5 | 10.6 | 0.6 |
| 25.8 | 0.9 | 39.03 | 0.08 |
| 27.26 | 0.09 | 44.61 | 0.35 |
| 25.04 | 0.13 | 37.7 | 0.6 |
| 2.4 | 0.5 | 50 | 0.8 |
| 0.92 | 0.21 | 3.1 | 0.5 |
| 57.69 | 0.34 | 21.8 | 0.8 |

**MWE**

```
from uncertainties import unumpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


A_n = 100 * np.random.rand(10)
A_s = np.random.rand(10)

B_n = 100 * np.random.rand(10)
B_s = np.random.rand(10)

AB = pd.DataFrame({'A':unumpy.uarray(A_n, A_s), 'B': unumpy.uarray(B_n, B_s)})


AB_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('A.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter', options={'strings_to_numbers': True})
AB.to_excel(AB_writer, sheet_name = 'Data', index=False, na_rep='nan')
AB_writer.close()
```

**Update**

I forgot to mention that AB is not created as shown in MWE, but is a result of previous calculations not given in the MWE. For the sake of MWE, I created the AB. So in short, I won't have access to the A and B nominal and uncertainty values.

Comment: If  you have no access to the A and B nominal and uncertainty values, how can you process these 2 columns and transform them ?   Or, you only have their combined values e.g. `63.2+/-0.9` in text ?

Comment: I have only their combined values (after many calculations).

Answer (score 2):

All the answers do not take into account that OP is using the [uncertainties](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/index.html) package.
The correct answer to the question [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51557781/22196075) or [the user manual](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/numpy_guide.html) is to use

```
unumpy.nominal_values(arr)
```

and

```
unumpy.std_devs(arr)
```

where arr is your pandas column

Answer (score 0):

Just split them into different columns:

```py
Au = unumpy.uarray(A_n, A_s)
Bu = unumpy.uarray(B_n, B_s)
AB = pd.DataFrame({'A': unumpy.nominal_values(Au), 'A+/-': unumpy.std_devs(Au), 'B': unumpy.nominal_values(Bu), 'B+/-': unumpy.std_devs(Bu)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the column(s) to get the outcome you're looking for. The following code maps the `A` column (make sure to not assign two columns to the same column key `'+/-'`)

```
AB[['A', '+/-']] = AB.A.apply(lambda x: str(x).split('+/-')).to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split each column into one column of main value and one column of the uncertainties, as follows:

```
# add the column labels here if you have more columns to process
# e.g. `for col in AB[['A', 'B', 'C']]:` if you want to process columns `A`, `B` and `C`
for col in AB[['A', 'B']]:     
    AB[[col, f'{col}+/-']] = AB[col].str.split(r'\+/-', expand=True)

# sort the columns to put the related columns together
AB = AB.sort_index(axis=1)
```

It is not recommended to have 2 columns of the same column labels in the same dataframe.  Here, we name the `+/-` columns with together with their respective source column name in order to distinguish them.

Here, we also use [`.sort_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) to sort the column names to put related columns adjacent to each other.

**Result:**

```
print(AB)

       A  A+/-      B  B+/-
0   63.2   0.9   75.4   0.9
1  41.94  0.05  53.12  0.21
2    4.1   0.4  89.51  0.32
3   28.2   0.5   10.6   0.6
4   25.8   0.9  39.03  0.08
5  27.26  0.09  44.61  0.35
6  25.04  0.13   37.7   0.6
7    2.4   0.5   50.0   0.8
8   0.92  0.21    3.1   0.5
9  57.69  0.34   21.8   0.8
```

Comment: I get the error `ValueError: Columns must be same length as key`

Comment: @TomKurushingal  Are you having some columns not with the `+/-` sign?   If yes, please loop over the columns having the `+/-` sign only as I mentioned in comment of the code.  E.g. `for col in AB[['A', 'B']]` for only columns `A` and `B` with the `+/-` sign

Comment: @TomKurushingal  The loop in the first part is to help you automate looping over all columns with `+/-` sign.  Of course if you have only 1 or 2 columns, you can manually do it by e.g. `AB[['A', 'A+/-']] = AB['A'].str.split(r'\+/-', expand=True)` and also `AB[['B', 'B+/-']] = AB['B'].str.split(r'\+/-', expand=True)` with one column at a time.

Comment: @TomKurushingal I've edited my codes above to process only columns `A` and `B` as in your sample data.  In case you have other columns to process, just add it to the list of columns.  e.g. use `for col in AB[['A', 'B', 'C']]:` for the first line of codes, if you want to process columns `A`, `B` and `C`

Comment: @TomKurushingal  How's the solution works for you ?  Please advise.  Thanks!